# Открытие блока по клику с закрытием всех остальных. Повторный клик по блоку — закрытие этого блока

Tags: javascript, jquery

FAQ из 13 вопросов, все ответы скрыты. При клике на вопрос должен открываться ответ на него, а все остальные ответы (если есть открытые) должны закрыться. Повторный клик по вопросу (открытому то есть) должен закрыть этот ответ. Замучился... Никак не получается сделать закрытие по повторному клику. В итоге, пока оставил так (всегда остаётся 1 открытый вопрос). Помогите, разобраться, я новичок. Желательно, чтобы было универсально, так как кол-во вопросов периодически меняется, что-то удаляется из середины списка, а что-то добавляется.

```css
ul {
 list-style-type: none;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
 font-size: 14pt !important;
 text-align: justify;
 } 
.question {
 padding: 5px 0;
 }
.question span {
 border-bottom: 1px dashed #537098;
 padding: 0 1px;
 cursor: pointer;
 color: #537098;
 }
#answer1, #answer2, #answer3, #answer4, #answer5, #answer6, #answer7, #answer8, #answer9, #answer10, #answer11, #answer12, #answer13 {
 display: none;
 margin-left: 20px;
 padding: 10px 0 5px 10px;
 }
li p {
 padding: 5px;
 font-size: 14pt !important;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
 
 <li class="question" onclick="$('#answer1').slideDown(); $('#answer2, #answer3, #answer4, #answer5, #answer6, #answer7, #answer8, #answer9, #answer10, #answer11, #answer12, #answer13').slideUp();"><span>Вопрос 1</span></li>
 <li id="answer1">Ответ 1</li>
 
 <li class="question" onclick="$('#answer2').slideDown(); $('#answer1, #answer3, #answer4, #answer5, #answer6, #answer7, #answer8, #answer9, #answer10, #answer11, #answer12, #answer13').slideUp();"><span>Вопрос 2</span></li>
 <li id="answer2">Ответ 2</li>
 
 <li class="question" onclick="$('#answer3').slideDown(); $('#answer1, #answer2, #answer4, #answer5, #answer6, #answer7, #answer8, #answer9, #answer10, #answer11, #answer12, #answer13').slideUp();"><span>Вопрос 3</span></li>
 <li id="answer3">Ответ 3</li>
 
 <li class="question" onclick="$('#answer4').slideDown(); $('#answer1, #answer2, #answer3, #answer5, #answer6, #answer7, #answer8, #answer9, #answer10, #answer11, #answer12, #answer13').slideUp();"><span>Вопрос 4</span></li>
 <li id="answer4">Ответ 4</li>
  
 </ul>
```

Comment: зачем вы вопросы и ответы в разные элементы списка помещаете?

Answer (score 1):

У вас есть одна большая сущность - `Вопрос`. Вопрос может иметь ответ, а может и не иметь. Начните с того, что используйте для одной сущности, один элемент списка. Не надо разделать вопрос и ответ в разные `li`. Элементы списка обычно представляют однородные элементы, у вас то вопрос то ответ, логика ломается, смысла это не имеет, код и верстка усложняются.

Пусть ответ будет вложенным в `li`, как и `span` с вопросом

Далее, класс `.question` вы сделали, почему бы не сделать класс `.answer` ? зачем эти `#answer1`. Вы в css написали одно правило для кучу этих `#answerХ` , должно быть очевидным, что надо сделать класс?

Не вставляйте js код прям внутрь html. забудьте про `onclick`-атрибуты, так писали лет 15 назад.

```js
$(".question span").click(function(){
   var $a = $(this).next(".answer");
   $(".answer").not($a).slideUp();
   $a.slideToggle();
});
```

```css
ul {
 list-style-type: none;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
 font-size: 14pt !important;
 text-align: justify;
 } 
.question {
 padding: 5px 0;
 }
.question span {
 border-bottom: 1px dashed #537098;
 padding: 0 1px;
 cursor: pointer;
 color: #537098;
 }
.answer {
 display: none;
 margin-left: 20px;
 padding: 10px 0 5px 10px;
 }
li p {
 padding: 5px;
 font-size: 14pt !important;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="question">
     <span>Вопрос 1</span>
    <div class="answer">Ответ 1</div>
  </li> 
  <li class="question">
    <span>Вопрос 2</span>
    <div class="answer">Ответ 2</div>
  </li>
 
  <li class="question">
    <span>Вопрос 3</span>
    <div class="answer">Ответ 3</div>
  </li>
 
  <li class="question" >
    <span>Вопрос 4</span>
    <div class="answer">Ответ 4</div>
  </li>
  
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(".questions-block").on('click', ".question", function (e) {
  var $this = $(this)
  
  if ($this.hasClass('open')) {
    $this.removeClass('open').next().slideUp()
  } else {
    $this.closest(".questions-block").find(".question.open").next().slideUp()
    $this.addClass('open').next().slideDown()
  }
})
```

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  font-size: 14pt;
  text-align: justify;
}

.question {
  padding: 5px 0;
}

.question span {
  border-bottom: 1px dashed #537098;
  padding: 0 1px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #537098;
}

.answer {
  display: none;
  margin-left: 20px;
  padding: 10px 0 5px 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="questions-block">
  <li class="question"><span>Вопрос 1</span></li>
  <li id="answer1" class="answer">Ответ 1</li>

  <li class="question"><span>Вопрос 2</span></li>
  <li id="answer2" class="answer">Ответ 2</li>

  <li class="question"><span>Вопрос 3</span></li>
  <li id="answer3" class="answer">Ответ 3</li>

  <li class="question"><span>Вопрос 4</span></li>
  <li id="answer4" class="answer">Ответ 4</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Если делать по вашей HTML разметке, то вот так:

```css
ul {
 list-style-type: none;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
 font-size: 14pt !important;
 text-align: justify;
 } 
.question {
 padding: 5px 0;
 }
.question span {
 border-bottom: 1px dashed #537098;
 padding: 0 1px;
 cursor: pointer;
 color: #537098;
 }
#answer1, #answer2, #answer3, #answer4, #answer5, #answer6, #answer7, #answer8, #answer9, #answer10, #answer11, #answer12, #answer13 {
 display: none;
 margin-left: 20px;
 padding: 10px 0 5px 10px;
 }
li p {
 padding: 5px;
 font-size: 14pt !important;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>

<li class="question"><span>Вопрос 1</span></li>
<li id="answer1">Ответ 1</li>

<li class="question"><span>Вопрос 2</span></li>
<li id="answer2">Ответ 2</li>

<li class="question"><span>Вопрос 3</span></li>
<li id="answer3">Ответ 3</li>

<li class="question"><span>Вопрос 4</span></li>
<li id="answer4">Ответ 4</li>
 
</ul>

<script>
  $('.question').each(function() {
    $(this).on('click', function() {
      $('.question').not($(this)).next().slideUp();
      $(this).next().slideToggle(); //чтобы можно было скрыть при повторном нажатии
    });
  });
</script>
```